# Can't ping or traceroute through AWS IPSec VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipsec, amazon-vpc, site-to-site-vpn

My VPC is connected to my premises via IPSec VPN, tunnel is shown to be UP on AWS console.

**Things that work:**

- I can see the traffic from my premises (subnet 192.168.0.0/16) to AWS VPC ( 10.0.0.0/16) on VPC flowlogs, marked as accepted.
- When I do a tcp dump of the ICMP traffic on terminal using `sudo tcpdump -i eth0 icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo` , I do see the ping:

`06:32:13.446579 IP ip-192-168-234-254.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal > graylog: ICMP echo request, id 17473, seq 18722, length 44` .

- I can get ping replies when I ping the AWS instance using its public IP, from everywhere.
- I can get ping replies when I ping the AWS instance using its private IP from another AWS instance in the same VPC.

**Things that don't work:**

- I can't get a ping reply when pinging from my premises to any of the
  AWS instances, including the one that receives my icmp ping.
- I can't get a ping reply when pinging from my AWS instance to my premises.
- I can't do a traceroute from my AWS instance to `192.168.234.254` or
  any of the other private IPs in my premises. These traceroutes end up
  with timeouts, just asterisk all the way.
- I can't do a traceroute
  from my premises to any of the AWS instances. These traceroutes end
  up with timeouts, just asterisk all the way.

**Configurations:**

Route Table for the subnet:

```
Destination        target        status    propagated
10.0.0.0/16        local         Active    No
0.0.0.0/16       igw-f06e2d95    Active    No
192.168.0.0/16   vgw-d1084e83    Active    No
```

Security group of AWS instances:
Inbound:

```
Type          Protocol    Port Range    Source
All ICMP      All          N/A      0.0.0.0/0
```

Outbound:

```
Type          Protocol    Port Range    Source
All Traffic      All          N/A      0.0.0.0/0
All Traffic      All          N/A      192.168.0.0/16
```

Network ACL inbound:

```
Rule#    Type            Protocol     Port Range        Source        Allow/Deny
100      All Traffic      ALL          ALL          0.0.0.0/0          ALLOW
200      All Traffic      ALL          ALL          192.168.0.0/16     ALLOW
*        All Traffic      ALL          ALL          0.0.0.0/0          DENY
```

Network ACL outbound

```
Rule#    Type            Protocol     Port Range        Source        Allow/Deny
100      All Traffic      ALL          ALL          0.0.0.0/0          ALLOW
200      All Traffic      ALL          ALL          192.168.0.0/16     ALLOW
\*        All Traffic      ALL          ALL          0.0.0.0/0          DENY
```

Trace path from my AWS instance to the IP on my premises shows:

```
tracepath ip-192-168-234-254.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
 1?: \[LOCALHOST\]                                         pmtu 9001
 1:  ip-10-0-2-1.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal           0.082ms pmtu 1500
 1:  no reply
 2:  no reply
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
 5:  no reply
 6:  no reply
```

Other info:
My AWS instance is running Ubuntu 14.04

In short: Traffic from my premises does reach my VPC instance, but I can't get a ping reply or traceroutes in both directions, even though the security groups and network ACLs are set up properly and even though I can get ping replies from within my VPC.

Comment: Certainly you don't really care about ICMP traffic? What services need to be reachable and are they?

Comment: Your routing tables, security groups and Network ACLs all look good. Try removing SGs and nACLs one by one and see if the problem resolves.

Comment: @M.Glatki  I've managed to fix it.  It was actually the Static Route at the VPN Connections page. Both the pings and the trace routes are working now.

Answer (score 1):

It was actually the Static Route at the VPN Connections page - I had missed out the step to add a static route to route traffic of certain IPs through the VPN.

For example, if the subnet at your premises uses IPs 173.112.0.0/16:

Add 173.112.0.0/16 under 'IP Prefixes'.

Note that the IP Prefixes column only accepts CIDR blocks. You can add individual IPs by using a /32 CIDR block if you wish to be more restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to do traceroute after adding the static route? I have everything configured, but still can't complete traceroute. I can see the traffic leaving the VPN interface, but not coming back (pinging both ways), so I'm thinking something is blocking it on the on-premise side. I wanted to know if you were able to complete the traceroute at least to the first few hops. I'm getting stars all the way even though it looks like the packets are leaving the VPN out interface.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/518950)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).